# Separate application log data from server log data using log4j

Tags: logging, selenium, log4j

I am creating a java application which starts a server (Selenium server), performs some actions (run automation tests) and shuts down the server in the end. I am using log4j as the logging framework. The log that is generated contains log data which is sent by my application as well as that which is generated by the server. My log4j.properties is as shown -

```
log4j.rootCategory=info,R1,R2

log4j.appender.R2=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.R2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.category.com.xyz.abc.tests=info, R1

log4j.appender.R1.File=C:/my_log.log
log4j.appender.R1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

My question is how do I separate the log data that is sent by my application from that which is generated by the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should provide appender for that package/category  :
`log4j.category.<selenium-pkg>=<level>, <appender>`
for example:
`log4j.category.org.openqa.selenium=INFO, R2`

Comment: Hi, I made that change but both the log files for the 2 appenders have the same contents - log data from the server as well as the application. Not sure where I am going wrong. My new entry is like this - 
log4j.category.org.openqa.selenium=info,R2
log4j.appender.R2.File=C:/selserver.log
log4j.appender.R2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n

Comment: it is because of you have specified both the appender as root appender!

Comment: Glad to know. are you using [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks)?

Comment: I might seem naive but how do I know if I am using JUnit or TestNG or ISFW? I don't think I am using any of these